# Formula for wavelength emitted taking into account the quantum orbital number $l$

Tags: visible-light, atomic-physics, wavelength, hydrogen, rydberg-states

Rydberg's formula can be used to find the wavelength emitted due to an electron moving from one energy level $n_i$ to another one $n_f$. But when the Schrödinger's model of the atom is introduced we learn that there is more than one quantum number, known as  $l$ and $m$. How can one calculate the wavelength of a photon emitted taking into account, for example, the quantum number $l$? Is there any formula?

For example, in the image I attached why is it that when the electron moves from the level 3d to the level 2p the light emitted is red? I mean is it always the case that the emitted light only depends on the quantum number n? and well one would have to add the condition $\Delta l=l_{i}-l_{f}=\pm1$

Sorry if is some sort of obvious question but I couldn't find any information (or didn't search well enough) that would help me confirm this assumption. Thanks in advance.

[image: Simulation]

Comment: Check the "fine structure of hydrogen" from any standard book. Basically you add perturbations (relativistic effects and spin-orbit coupling) to the original Hamiltonian and that leads to breaking the degeneracy in $l$, i.e. the energy expression has additional correction terms with $l$ - dependence.

Comment: :o Thanks a lot for the reference. Another question, for the hydrogen atom is it always the case that the energy transitions occur in the same n levels? That is, I can have a transition from $n_1$ to $n_2$ in the Bohr Model and for the Schrodinger model I will get the same transition $n_1$ -> $n_2$ and those would include all the possible combinations for different values of $l$ right?

Comment: Yes, it would include all possible combinations for different $l$.

The Bohr model is an oversimplified model of an atom - it captures only the idea that the emission spectrum is discrete. But there is more to the emission spectrum than just being discrete. When u look closer, you can see that each of those spectral lines are basically many thinner spectral lines bunched together. Now this is something Bohr model can't explain. You must use a better model to explain this - wave functions, Schrodinger equation and perturbation theory.